# Syntax problem of bacth sql execution in procedure

Tags: mysql

Failed to run followwing code in mysql 8.0.

```
 drop table if exists test ;
 create table if not exists  test(rowid int);
 delimiter$$ 
   drop procedure if exists line_sum $$  
   create procedure line_sum()
   begin    
     declare i int ;
     declare exe_sql varchar(100);  
        set i=5 ;           
        while i>0  do 
          set exe_sql  = concat('alter table test add column d ',i,' int') ; 
          prepare ppsql from exe_sql ; 
          execute ppsql   ; 
          deallocate prepare ppsql  ; 
          set i = i-1;
        end while ;
    end$$
delimiter ;
```

It reported:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'while i>0  do 
   set exe_sql  = concat('alter table test add column d ',i,' int' 
at line 11
```

However my colleague and I have checked it many times, finding no issues in the syntax and getting more confusion.

Comment: User-defined variable, not local variable, must be used as a parameter with SQL code in PREPARE. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4579d97219d94eacf40fab8064b03b6

Comment: Your error code claims that there is some non-printable errorneous char before WHILE keyword. Or you have some another but similar problem.

Comment: PS. The SQL code generated in your SP is synthactically wrong (excess space char) and will fail. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0627484db145cb42a7988f92ce3b4a4f